# Different fonts/glyphs inside same document or equation

Tags: fonts, equations, pdftex

Coulomb's law equation is a vector equation, whose scalar content is, schematically:

F = qq'/r^2.

More exactly, I have to present this really as a vector equation and such that the glyph 'r' assumes two variants (''normal'' and ''bold''), distinct from the usual CM font glyph 'r'.

I use TexLive's pdflatex, in (K)Ubuntu 20.4 (Focal Fossa), and am able to use the glyphs from the official proprietary mtpro2 package like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[mtpscr]{mtpro2}
% The call to the variant \altr, in the ``normal'' and ``bold'' versions, 
% is carried out, respectively, by the comands: \mathscr{\altr} and
% mathbscr{\altr}, always in math mode.

\begin{document}
    
\begin{align}
\vec{\mathbold{F}} &= \dfrac{qq'}{\mathscr{\altr}^2}\,\hat{\mathbscr{\altr}} \\
&= \dfrac{qq'}{\mathscr{\altr}^3}\,\vec{\mathbscr{\altr}} \\
&= \dfrac{qq'}{|\mathbold{r} - \mathbold{r}'|^3}\,(\mathbold{r}-\mathbold{r}')\,,
\end{align}
where, of course,
\begin{equation}
\mathbscr{\altr} := \mathbold{r} - \mathbold{r}'\,.
\end{equation}

$\mathbold{q}, q$ as opposed to q

\end{document}
```

which provides a nice rendering. I could live with that...

However, I would like to tweak it a little bit more: what I would really like is to use, inside the align environment, the glyph 'q' from the usual Computer Modern font, instead of the one from the mtpro2 package, if possible, like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage[mtpscr]{mtpro2}
% The call to the variant \altr, in the ``normal'' and ``bold'' versions, 
% is carried out, respectively, by the comands: \mathscr{\altr} and
% mathbscr{\altr}, always in math mode.

\begin{document}
    

$q$ as opposed to q

\end{document}
```

That is: is it possible, inside the same formula or equation, to use glyphs from distinct fonts??

Thanks

PS: I tried to find my way to append some images of the output pdf's, but did not succeed. Any help concerning this is welcome as well.

Comment: Wikipedia does it like `{\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {F_{1}}}={q_{1}q_{2} \over 4\pi \varepsilon _{0}}{({\boldsymbol {r_{1}-r_{2}}}) \over |{\boldsymbol {r_{1}-r_{2}}}|^{3}}={q_{1}q_{2} \over 4\pi \varepsilon _{0}}{{\boldsymbol {{\widehat {r}}_{12}}} \over |{\boldsymbol {r_{12}}}|^{2}}}` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law#Vector_form), maybe that would be an alternative? Disclaimer: I don't know anything about the physics of electromagnetism :)

Comment: I am aware of this or other possibilities, but I do really want to learn, if possible, how to use distinct fonts inside the same equation, or just a single glyph from another mathematical font, for that matter!